# Most efficient way to flatten Array<Array<T> | T> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I want to create a function that accepts an array of both arrays and literals (or maybe objects) and flattens it to a single dimensional array. For example a valid input would be `[5, [2, 3], 7, [9, 0, 1]]`, and the output of that input should be `[5, 2, 3, 7, 9, 0, 1]`.

This is the code I have so far. There is nothing wrong with it, I just want to make sure it's as efficient as possible (it also needs to be es5 compatible).

```js
function flattenArray(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    result.push(list[index] instanceof Array ? list[index] : [list[index]]);
  }
  return [].concat.apply([], result);
}

console.log(flattenArray([5, [2, 3], 7, [9, 0, 1]]));
```

Comment: please add an example of objects.

Comment: Can you have arrays (potentially) infinitely nested? For example, `[1, [2], [[3], 4], [[[[[5]]]]]]`, etc?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't need really have a need for infinite depth, right now the input is of type `Array<T | Array<T>>`

Comment: @nickzoum ok, just checking. a `Array<T | Array<T>>` should be easier to handle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/2308005 this anwer is correct

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using `Array.flat`

```js
function flattenArray(list) {
  return list.flat()
}

console.log(flattenArray([5, [2, 3], 7, [9, 0, 1]]));
```

This seems to be second fastest ( based on the test link attached below ) and ES5 compatible

```js
console.log([].concat.apply([],[5, [2, 3], 7, [9, 0, 1]]))
```

[`Performace test`](https://jsperfcom-gffcctkcvo.now.sh/array-flat)

Comment: The question has `ecmascript-5`tag so I'd assume it's not looking for new ES features.

Comment: @Clarity added one ES-5 compatible version too

Comment: @CodeManiac Didnt realise `Array#concat` accepted mixed inputs. This is obviously faster.

Comment: this will not work for nested arrays, like `[0, [1, [2, [3, [4], [5], [6, [7], [8], [9]]]]]]`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly [`OP's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476260/most-efficient-way-to-flatten-array-of-arrays-and-literals-in-javascript/57476291#comment101424458_57476260) this is what op has mentioned in comment

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly but someone should not just directly copy paste code from here to there requirements, they should atleast try to understand a bit as well as read the question and comment properly, and also there's a good dup target is also on the top,

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I don't think that the answers should also have to include another answer for questions that look like my question. Also i edited the title to make clarify the type.

Comment: @CodeManiac Did some [tests](http://jsben.ch/VLn9e), looks like `Array#push` is faster than `Array#concat`

Comment: @nickzoum when i run test it shows code block 2 (Array#concat ) is fastest, and also the test result will depend on the data set you're using for test, see the one i linked in question it uses a large data

Comment: @CodeManiac I created a benchmark with larger data [here](http://jsben.ch/ZZ7I9). It says `Array#flat` is the slowest and nested `Array#push` is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Cocerning your code: There is no sense in wrapping single elements into arrays, `.concat` will handle them correctly, in other words:

```
  [1].concat([2], 2)
```

just works, there is no need for wrapping `2` into `[2]`. That turns your code into a oneliner.

Comment: All answers that I scrolled through also work for your usecase. What else do you need?

Comment: The answers on that question could be possible answers for this question as well, yes. But the question is clearly not the same, and none of those answers is the most efficient way, as you can see in the benchmark [here](http://jsben.ch/ZZ7I9).

Comment: That benchmark runs on a very small sample set without any iterations. Whatever conclusion you try to draw from that is wrong.

Comment: It's 500 iterations, also `http://jsben.ch` doesn't work if a case takes too long, it says that all the cases run in 0ms. Here's a [benchmark](http://jsben.ch/Mbpdk) with somewhat larger data (but without any iterations).